# VBA - Parsing Date from Free Form Text String

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to parse out clean target DATES from cells populated with free form TEXT STRINGS.

ie: TEXT STRING: "ETA: 11/22 (Spring 4.5)" or "ETA 10/30/2019 EOD"

As you can see, there is no clear standard for the position of the date in the string, rendering LEFT or RIGHT formulas futile.

I tried leveraging a VBA function that I found which essentially breaks up the string into parts based on spaces in the string; however it has not been working.

```
Public Function GetDate(ResNotes As String) As Date

    Dim TarDate As Variant
    Dim part As Variant

    TarDate = Split(ResNotes, " ")

    For Each part In ResNotes
        If IsDate(part) = True Then
           GetDate = part
           Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    GetDate = "1/1/2001"
End Function
```

I'm referring to the cells with text strings as "ResNotes", short for "Resolution Notes" which is the title of the column

"TarDate" refers to the "Target Date" that I am trying to parse out

The result of the custom GETDATE function in Excel gives me a #NAME? error.

I expected the result to give me something along the lines of "10/30/2019"

Comment: Can't post an answer right now but have a search for 'regex vba', it's a class designed for just this kind of thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need VBA for some other part of your project, this can also be done using worksheet formulas:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,DATEVALUE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),1)
```

where `seq_99` is a named formula and refers to:

```
=IF(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,255,1))=1,1,(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,255,1))-1)*99)
```

*`seq_99` generates an array of numbers `{1;99;198;297;396;495;...`

Format the cell with the formula as a **Date** of some type.

[image]

If there are no dates, it will return an error which you can either leave, or wrap the function in an `IFERROR(your_formula,your_error_message)`

#### Algorithm

- Split the cell on the spaces

  - Replace each space with 99 spaces
  - Using the `MID` function, return an array of substrings 99 characters long
- Apply the `DATEVALUE` function which will return either an error (if the substring is not a date) or a date serial number.
- Since dates in Excel are serial numbers since 1/1/1900, we can use the `AGGREGATE` function to pick out a value, and ignore errors.

Comment: Oi, you're an absolute champ. Thank you, sir!

Comment: Ron, your formula works like a charm, I'm wondering what the "seq_99" logic is though, how exactly does it work if you don't mind explaining this to me...

Comment: @MiguelZaldivar The formula *seq_99 generates an array of numbers {1;99;198;297;396;495;...*  Similar to `ROW(INDIRECT("1:n"))` but is non-volatile.  Or `ROW(1:10)` which would generate `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10}`

Comment: Hey I validated your answer, Ron, thank you again. I was wondering why seq_99 references 255 in the row field for the Index formula. Is the 255 arbitrary?

Comment: @MiguelZaldivar The original formula was developed by `Harlan Grove` and was actually `=ROW(INDEX($A$1:$A$65535,1,1):INDEX($A$1:$A$65535,255,1))`. This was for earlier versions of Excel and generated the maximum size array available. Earlier versions could not use whole column references, and had a maximum number of columns = 255.

Comment: Very instructive; always something to learn by your posts :-) @RonRosenfeld

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting `#NAME` then the code is not stored in a general module. It should NOT be in a worksheet module or ThisWorkbook module.

Also there are few errors in the code.  Split returns a `String` Array.  And since IsDate returns `TRUE/FALSE` the `= True` is not needed.

As per [@MathieuGuindon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610431/vba-parsing-date-from-free-form-text-string/58610567?noredirect=1#comment103532242_58610567) we can change the string to a date in the code if found and return an error if not.  For that we need to allow the return to be a variant.

```
Public Function GetDate(ResNotes As String)

    Dim TarDate() As String
    Dim part As Variant

    TarDate = Split(ResNotes, " ")

    For Each part In TarDate
        If IsDate(part) Then
           GetDate = CDate(part)
           Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    GetDate = "1/1/2001"
    'Instead of a hard coded date, one can return an error, just use the next line instead
    'GetDate =CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Comment: Hm, I'd probably make the function return a `Variant`, and yield `CVErr(xlErrValue)` instead of a magic hard-coded default if the string can't be parsed.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon then would we not need to convert the string to a double: `GetDate = cdbl(part)` or something like that so it does not return the string?

Comment: Good point, missed that =) ...although, why not do `CDate(part)` and return a `Variant/Date`?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon frankly did not think it made a difference, but as we all know am more "hack" than "programmer". :)

Comment: You guys are absolute legends of the sport. Thank you both so much! I also was getting the #NAME error because I saved the module the same as the function name - rookie mistake.

Comment: @MiguelZaldivar please mark one of the answers as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer you used.

Comment: Just for the sake of the art - posted another approach using `Filter` function in combination with `Split` +)

Answer (score 0):

**Approach isolating the date string via `Filter` function**

Just for fun another approach demonstrating the use of the `Filter` function in combination with `Split` to isolate the **date string** and split it into **date tokens** in a second step; finally these tokens are transformed to date using `DateSerial`:

```
Function getDat(rng As Range, Optional ByVal tmp = " ") As Variant
  If rng.Cells.count > 1 Then Set rng = rng.Cells(1, 1)             ' allow only one cell ranges
  If Len(rng.value) = 0 Then getDat = vbNullString: Exit Function   ' escape empty cells
' [1] analyze cell value; omitted year tokens default to current year
'     (valid date strings must include at least one slash, "11/" would be interpreted as Nov 1st)
  tmp = Filter(Split(rng.Value2, " "), Match:="/", include:=True)   ' isolate Date string
  tmp = Split(Join(tmp, "") & "/" & Year(Now), "/")                 ' split Date tokens
' [2] return date
  Const M% = 0, D% = 1, Y& = 2                                      ' order of date tokens
  getDat = VBA.DateSerial(Val(tmp(Y)), Val(tmp(M)), _
                          IIf(tmp(D) = vbNullString, 1, Val(tmp(D))))
End Function
```